# How slice PSDs on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, adobe-photoshop, web-development, gimp

I really hate booting into Windows 7 just to boot up Ps to cut out some stuff and then flip back to Ubuntu... plus, if I missed something or other, its a mega pain to reboot again.

Gimp also doesn't work well for this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As just Tom said, you will have to find a VM. The choices avaliable are:

[KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page): It's the 'new' virtualization, it comes with the kernel. You have to install a single application and you can either manage your virtual machine by console or you can do this with 'libvirt' ([virt-manager](http://virt-manager.et.redhat.com/)). (3D support is the same as Virtualbox, read below. It's not really good so some operations may be slower than on Windows due to the lack of openGL accel.)

[VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/): Commercial software, not really cheap but the best. It provides stable, excellent 3D performance, awesomeness when it comes to Photoshop (since I also do some graphical work when I have to and Workstation just does what I want.)

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/): Free virtualization software by Oracle (*cough* Sun). It's not the best, the 3D is very buggy (it's just a hack from/by Wine sadly), but it's free. Give it a spin and see whether it does the job or not. For me, I experienced too many bugs to stay with VirtualBox.

[Parallel Workstations](http://www.parallels.com/eu/landingpage/dskd39_3/?source=g_eu&gclid=CKrgyPDRxaMCFQE9ZgodD2mMXg): A good virtualization software again. However, I never had a chance to test it for a very long time.

Oh how could I forgot [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/). Nowadays it's just like a free VMWare Workstation. Back then you couldn't make guests with it, but it's all solved now. Also you can just grab guest images from the web from sites like [this](http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/).

Comment: I really only want to slice out images, test in IE7-9(so ill be wanting to run W7 Home Premium probably) in windows. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: I'd first try VMWare Player. Then VirtualBox (since it's still free), then maybe Workstation. (its not free, sadly. But even the openGL accel is working purrfectly in PS).

Answer (score 0):

Why not run Windows in a Virtualbox VM? That gets rid of the reboot problem completely.

Since you're doing web development, you could make the VM run a Windows server instead, which would also give you an always-available server for testing.